# C# Selenium Monitor and kill higher CPU usage processes

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, cpu-usage, specflow

The stack that I am using is C# and Specflow and I am running the tests on multiple threads.I have some automation tests on web application. I am executing them headless on remote Linux machine.

I've noticed that some of the tests on one of the features is adding way higher CPU usage than the tests for the other features(up to 100%). The same thing is happening when executing the tests manually. I've noticed that if I kill the Google Chrome process with highest CPU usage, the execution continues without problem.

Is there a way, that I can monitor the CPU usage during test execution and automatically kill the process with highest usage?

If the monitoring during execution is possible, I was thinking to either wait for 100% CPU usage and kill the process with the highest usage or wait for Google Chrome process to exceed for example 40-50% CPU usage and then kill it.

Comment: This might indicate a problem with the application that should be addressed by the developers. Maybe JavaScript has entered into some kind of infinite loop, or some sort of intensive operation. If you can reproduce this manually, I would say you have a performance problem, not an automated testing problem. The automated test is working fine. The application? Not so much.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? That might be an issue.

Comment: I still feel like you have uncovered a performance problem in the web application, rather than a problem with the test.

Comment: I am using the last compatible chromedriver and chrome. The CPU Usage is comming from canva element that is invoking a lot of lambdas to visualise models on it. I cannot stop the request and the visualization, but killing the right chrome is removing the canva and the usage is back to normal levels.